# TarPit not working in Mavericks

Tags: macos, compression

One of my favorite applications appears not to be working after making the upgrade to Mavericks. I am referring to [TarPit](http://tarpit.en.softonic.com/mac) which creates easily archives for me. I just loved this application since on command line creating a tar.gz would also include the .DS_Store files, and other similar nonsense.

So, is there a workaround and making TarPit work again? Is there an alternative to TarPit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this alias in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias tarc='COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar --exclude .DS_Store -c'
```

It can be used like `tarc -zf directory.tgz directory` or `tarc -f directory.tar directory`.

Setting COPYFILE_DISABLE tells tar to remove extended attributes, ACLs, resource forks, and Finder information. tar uses AppleDouble files (the files that start with ._) to store metadata by default, and it also knows how to convert metadata stored in AppleDouble files back to the native formats, but unarchiving applications on other platforms usually keep the ._ files.

```
$ touch a;xattr -w key value a;tar -cf a.tar a;tar -tf a.tar
./._a
a
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -cf a2.tar a;tar -tf a2.tar
a
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a very interesting answer! I will let it rest for a while, and if no one else gives another answer soon, then I will accept.

Comment: I am accepting because otherwise I will forget it. Thanks again for sharing the alias! : )